# How to change all the numbers in a list to have the same amount of digits - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of numbers that I am reading from a file. I want to make it so the length of the numbers is all the same based on what I want it to be (7 digits, 4 digits, etc.). If there is a 5 and I want it to be 4 digits, I'd want the output to be 5.000 and if there was a 1048 and I want 4 digits It would already be in the correct digit place

```
firstline = line.strip().replace('\t', ' ').split()[1:]
trythis = (map(float, (firstline)))
print(list(trythis))
for i in range(len(firstline)):
    trythis[i] = round(trythis[i], 4)
print(list(trythis))

[0.0, 0.053, 0.105, 0.158, 0.211, 0.263, 0.316, 0.368, 0.421, 0.474, 0.526, 0.579, 0.632, 0.684, 0.737, 0.789, 0.842, 0.895, 0.947, 1.0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    trythis[i] = round(trythis[i], 4)
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: map is not indexable - use a list: `trythis = list(map(float, (firstline)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following condition "%.xf" (x being the number of digits you wnat to display after the comma) :

```
list_1  =[1.2, 1.345, 1.32]
list_2 = ["%.3f" % x for x in list_1]

print(list_2)
['1.200', '1.345', '1.320']
```

Or you could cast your number into a string and check their length :

```
list_1  =[1.2, 1.345, 1.32]
len_wanted = 5
list_2 = [x if len(str(x))==len_wanted  else str(x)+'0'*(len_wanted -len(str(x))) for x in list_1]

print(list_2)
['1.200', 1.345, '1.320']
```